# Creating a trigger in SQL Server for the appropriate table based on the logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an `InventoryOnHand` table with a `Quantity` column.

When an `InventoryTransaction` record is INSERTED, I need to update the `Quantity` in the `InventoryOnHand` table.

Can someone please explain the following:

1. Should the trigger created in the `InventoryOnHand` table or the `InventoryTransaction` table? I would assume the `InventoryTransaction` table since this is the 'INSERTED'
2. When naming the trigger, should the tablename be the updated table or the actual table with the trigger applied to it? For example: `tr_InventoryTransactionIns`

**Here is what I have:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_InventoryTransactionIns 
   ON  dbo.Inventory 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    UPDATE Inventory SET QuantityOnHand = QuantityOnHand + INSERTED.Quantity
END
GO
```

Comment: **(1)** : yes, the trigger has to be on the table where the action *causing* the trigger occurs; you want to fire the trigger when data is inserted into the `InventoryTransaction` table - so the trigger **must be** on this table. **(2)**: that's entirely up to you and your naming conventions - there isn't any "accepted" best practice or generally accepted convention here - define something for your team / company and stick to it

Comment: @marc_s one last question. In what case will multiple records be in the INSERTED table versus a single record? I am going to assume if the code does a SELECT INSERT then there would be multiple. But if it just does a for each loop and makes a database call each time they would each be individual right?

Comment: You need to consider and deal with the possibility of having multiple rows in the `Inserted` table - see my response - use a proper **set-based** approach to handle this in a single `UPDATE` statement. You should ***never ever*** put loops or cursor inside a trigger - that would be the death of any performance in your system!

Comment: Instead of using triggers I would suggest to update InventoryOnHand table in the stored procedure itself i.e. when a row is inserted into InventoryTransaction table after this update InventoryOnHand table and both should be within a transaction.

Comment: @TheShooter I have been trying to avoid using triggers, but I was thinking if data is entered through the back-end it is the only way to keep things in sync. Additionally I am not using stored procs in my c# code I am using entity framework. So yeah I could rely completely on the code to do the correct thing and wrap it in a transaction, but I want to try and make it foolproof.

Comment: I really don't know about entity framework. If stored procedure isn't an option then trigger seems to be the only choice. I would check if entity framework has something which can support transactions so that you can perform an insert and update in same transaction. You can check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx and this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: @TheShooter hmm I think I am going to go that path actually and not worry about the trigger since Entity Framework does support transactions!

Comment: This shines a light on that oft-argued idea - should business rules be in the database or in the application layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to somehow *link* the rows being inserted with the rows you're updating in the `Inventory` table -right now, you're updating **the entire** `Inventory` table!

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_InventoryTransactionIns 
ON dbo.InventoryTransaction
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE inv
    SET QuantityOnHand = QuantityOnHand + INSERTED.Quantity
    FROM Inventory inv
    INNER JOIN Inserted ins ON inv.InventoryId = ins.InventoryId
END
GO
```

Comment: Good catch I can't believe I forgot the to use the InventoryId. I believe it needs to be inv.QuantityOnHand + INSERTED.Quantity and inv.Id = ins.InventoryId if you want to update your post. Is there any specific reason your doing an INNER JOIN instead of a normal update statement with a where clause?

Comment: INNER JOIN is sql-92 (newest version of SQL) whereas WHERE is the older version. Functionally they are the same (when defining join predicates)